# What is the difference between `leanprover` and `leanprover-community` GitHub repositories?

Tags: lean, lean-community, github-repository

I keep bumping into references to "Lean", but then find there are two GitHub repositories for Lean:

- https://github.com/leanprover

  and
- https://github.com/leanprover-community

Can someone explain the difference? Is one better than the other, or do they have different purposes?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

https://github.com/leanprover is the official Lean organization, and contains the original works being built by Leo de Moura and his team. It also is in particular where development of [Lean 4](https://github.com/leanprover/lean4) is happening.

https://github.com/leanprover-community is run by the broader Lean community, albeit in close contact with the Lean developers (some of whom contribute to repositories in both organizations). It hosts the community website and resources, but also [Mathlib](https://github.com/leanprover-community/mathlib4), which is in some sense Lean's "killer app" -- over a million lines of mathematics built by many mathematicians and contributors, and with extremely active continued work. As of July 2023, it has been fully migrated to Lean 4.

The leanprover-community repository also hosts a community website, including instructions for [getting started](https://leanprover-community.github.io/get_started.html) with Lean 4 and Mathlib.

Comment: Thanks! I clarified. And no worries / rush on the internet points :)

Comment: Of interest: YouTube Lean 3 tutorial videos ([Play List](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLlF-CfQhukNnxF1S22cNGKyfOrd380NUv)) which include videos of installing on [Mac](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NOGWsCNm_FY&list=PLlF-CfQhukNnxF1S22cNGKyfOrd380NUv), [Windows](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y3GsHIe4wZ4&list=PLlF-CfQhukNnxF1S22cNGKyfOrd380NUv) and [Ubuntu](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=02ff4WrW0FU&list=PLlF-CfQhukNnxF1S22cNGKyfOrd380NUv)